# Lightbox facebook iframe, video embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe, magnific-popup

I have been trying to Magnific Popup (a lightbox) to load facebook video embed iframes. Previously I was using PrettyPhoto, however I wanted to make the switch. Strangely, utilizing the same methodology I have in the following codepen the iframe fails to load properly (e.g. within the bounds of the player) for Facebook. [image] I realized the same thing was happening with PrettyPhoto, and I believe that Facebook might have made a change.

```
<a class="video" href="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed/?_rdr=p&video_id=1291445700871053">Open Facebook video here</a>
```

JS

```
$('.video').magnificPopup({
  type: 'iframe'
});
```

Does anyone know how to mitigate this issue?

http://codepen.io/afagard/pen/YWyoOP

Comment: +1 for Rickrolling me. The first time I looked (FF/Win7), it was just showing the thumbnail, not playing the video, but now it's playing the video as well. Perhaps it was a temporary issue?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg just trying to keep things lively. But actually, I wasn't referring to the fact that it loads, but rather, that it doesn't load within the box so users will have to technically scroll down or up to see the video (image).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like Facebook changed the HTML they created for the embed_html version of the video player.

You can use this link instead to make that work:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvideo.php%3Fv%3D{VIDEO_ID}
```

(You should change the {VIDEO_ID} at the end of the link with the ID of your video).

Your complete code should look like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Video Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/magnific-popup.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="video" href="https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvideo.php%3Fv%3D1291445700871053
">Open Facebook video here</a>
        <br><br><br>
        <a class="video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Open Youtube video here</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.video').magnificPopup({
                type: 'iframe'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is what I am currently doing, unfortunately it seems that facebook must have changed their code. It sucks because the people who post the videos can specify a no embed, and the original way I was using seemingly went around that and would show any video. I will wait to see if anyone comes up with any other magic; otherwise I will award you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex, the code I just gave you works exactly the way you want. You can always change the URL of all anchors who starts with `http://www.facebook.com/video/embed` into the new working url (using jQuery) before your call to magnificPopup.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook has updated their video embed URL. Try this
[https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2{PAGE_NAME}%2Fvideos%2F{VIDEO_ID}%2F](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2%7BPAGE_NAME%7D%2Fvideos%2F%7BVIDEO_ID%7D%2F)

- This URL you can get by embedding a video on facebook.